# How can I add a tab to the Product Information, and then have an iframe in the tab

Tags: product, adminhtml, tabs

I'd like to add an iframe to the product tab for every magento product. I am building a magento plugin that allows users to integrate magento with our own analytics control panel, and it would be great if they could click a tab within the product information admin backend on a per product basis to preview the performance of that product.

I have been reading similar questions on the Magento stack exchange but have failed to find something that can answer this question. I essentially just need to know what search times to use to find the answers.

From what I can tell it might involve using the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Main` class. I can't really work out whether I need to add something to my config.xml to get that class working or where to start with this.

A kick in the right direction here would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: I just found this which might be of some help: http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration but it doesn't explicitly explain how to add product edit tab

Answer (score 1):

So to add a tab without rewriting a core file I would suggest using the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`. This event will give you the block as an object so you can check to make sure that it is type `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs`, which is where the tabs are created.

```
$block = $observer->getBlock();
if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs) {
    // Code to add tab should go here
}
```

Then to add a tab you simply need to call the function `addTab` which takes an id for the tab, a label and the content. So to add another tab that display the inventory details again simply call:

```
$block->addTab(
    'new_tab',
    array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Inventory'),
        'content'   => Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory')->toHtml()
    )
);
```

Obviously to display your own custom tab replace the call to `adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory` with the call to your block.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, these links will be useful:

- http://www.atwix.com/magento/new-tab-product-edit-page/
- http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/

Comment: link only answers are not very good as the links can die over time. Could you summarize each approach please.

Answer (score 0):

Default of magento v2, product details page just showing 3 tabs are: Details, More Information and Reviews. With [Product Tabs](http://www.magesolution.com/extensions-for-magento/product-tabs-for-magento-2.html) admin can add unlimited tabs. The tab can be use static blocks or attributes. - See more at: http://www.magesolution.com/product-tabs-for-magento-2.html